# How to achieve incremental caching without data duplication in Dask?

Tags: dask

I'm trying to find the equivalent of Spark's `unpersist` in Dask. My need
for an explicit unpersist arises in a situation where:

- The calling context already has persisted a large `df`, e.g., because it needs
  to compute many aggregates for preprocessing purposes.
- The calling context calls a function, which also needs to call persist, e.g.,
  because it performs some iterative algorithm.

A basic example would look like:

```py
def iterative_algorithm(df, num_iterations):

    for iteration in range(num_iterations):

        # Transformation logic requiring e.g. map_partitions
        def mapper(df):
            # ...
            return df

        df = df.map_partitions(mapper)
        df = df.persist()
        # Now I would like to explicitly unpersist the old snapshot

    return df
```

In Spark, the problem could be solved by releasing the old snapshots
explicitly. Apparently Dask does not have an explicit `unpersist` but handles the problem
via reference counting of the underlying futures. This means that the example
above would duplicate the data, because the calling context holds references
to the old futures, while the sub-function holds references to the modified
persist. In my actual use case, there are several nested levels of such
transformation calls, causing the data to duplicate even multiple times.

Is there a way to solve iterative caching without any additional copies?

Answer (score 3):

*I'll post some ideas how to solve this, but I'm still looking for better
alternatives.*

Due to the reference counting, it is tricky to avoid the copies, but there
are possibilities. The problem is a result of the caller holding a reference
to the original `df` and the sub-function creating new instances via `df = df.<method>`
calls. To solve the problem we would have to make the reference to `df` itself
mutable. Unfortunately Python in general does not allow to mutate the reference
of function arguments.

**Solution 1: Naive mutable reference**

The most simple way to work-around that limitation is to wrap the `df` into a list
or dict. In this case the sub-function can modify the external reference, e.g. by:

```py
df_list[0] = df_list[0].map_partitions(mapper)
df_list[0] = df_list[0].persist()
```

However this is syntactically awkward and one has to be very careful, because
simplifying the syntax via `df = df_list[0]` again creates new references to
the underlying futures, which can cause data duplication.

**Solution 2: Wrapper-based mutable reference**

Improving on that, one could write a small wrapper class, which holds a reference
to a dataframe. Passing around this wrapper, the sub-functions can mutate
the reference. To improve on the syntax issue one might consider if the wrapper
should delegate functionality to the dataframe automatically or inherit
from it. Overall this solution also doesn't feel right.

**Solution 3: Explicit mutation**

To avoid the syntax issues of the other solutions I currently prefer the following
variant, which effectively simulates mutable versions of `map_partitions`
and `persist` via an inplace modification of the original `df` instance.

```py
def modify_inplace(old_df, new_df):
    # Currently requires accessing private fields of a DataFrame, but
    # maybe this could be officially supported by Dask.
    old_df.dask = new_df.dask
    old_df._meta = new_df._meta
    old_df._name = new_df._name
    old_df.divisions = new_df.divisions


def iterative_algorithm(df, num_iterations):

    for iteration in range(num_iterations):

        def mapper(df):
            # Actual transform logic...
            return df

        # Simulate mutable/in-place map_partitions
        new_df = df.map_partitions(mapper)
        modify_inplace(df, new_df)

        # Simulate mutable/in-place persist
        new_df = df.persist()
        modify_inplace(df, new_df)

    # Technically no need to return, because all operations were in-place
    return df
```

This works reasonably well for me, but requires to follow these rules carefully:

- Replace all immutable calls like `df = df.<method>` by the pattern above.
- Pay attention to creating references to `df`. For instance, using a variable like `some_col = df["some_sol"]` for syntactical convenience requires to `del some_col` before calling persist. Otherwise the reference stored withing `some_col` will again cause data duplication.

Comment: You will want to also include `df.divisions` in your `modify_inplace` function

Answer (score 3):

You could write a release function as follows:

```
from distributed.client import futures_of

def release(collection):
    for future in futures_of(collection):
        future.release()
```

This will only release the current instance.  If you have multiple instances of these futures lying around you might have to call it a few times or add a loop like the following:

```
while future.client.refcount[future.key] > 0:
```

But generally calling this multiple times seems unwise in case you have other copies floating around with reason.